# SQL statement for making foreign key

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
ALTER TABLE Chosen_doctor ADD FOREIGN KEY (doctor) 
REFERENCES Doctors (name) WHERE areaofexpertise LIKE `General%`  
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Is this plausible sql statement  i want to add to mz foreign key that it should onlz be referenced to doctors name if his area of expertise is general practitioner

Comment: I don't think foreign keys take `where` clauses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thanks but is it possible to make something like this.Because i need to allow only general practitioners to be choosen

Comment: Give a [mcve] so we can discuss specific transformations of your specific design.

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEYs` are integrity constraints, not ways to achieve selections.

An FK has the side effect of creating `INDEX`, but that is for performance, not for filtering.

Filtering is achieved by using a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement.

Also, complex restrictions on `DELETE` and `UPDATE` must be handled via `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can create constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE suppliers
ADD CONSTRAINT check_supplier_name
  CHECK (supplier_name IN ('IBM', 'Microsoft', 'NVIDIA'));
```

But I didn’t see FK with ‘%like%’. I think in generally rdbms conception is not support FK with ‘like’. You also may create function for your case(task) and add this function in trigger on table before insert for each row .